# Why SELECT can have SIU lock (SQL Server 2012)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, deadlock

Today I was troubleshooting a deadlock case and discovered a quite strange case (at least it seemed strange to me). I had two concurrent statements (`UPDATE` and `SELECT`) and they led to a deadlock scenario. No question there. Below is DeadLock graph which depicts my case:

[image: deadlock graph]

What bothers me is the type of lock which `SELECT` holds. Why is it `SIU` (Share with Intern Update), but not `S` (Shared) or `IS` (Intent Shared) lock?

I found a [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3e01df38-f5a4-48b0-9711-21126db921d7/siu-locks-during-select?forum=sqldatabaseengine) on MSDN forum, which explains quite similar case:

> Profiler shows current cumulative lock from all sessions. After I exported deadlock event to xdl-file and opened it in text editor I found that process which selects data has S lock and process that updates data has IU lock (and wants IX lock). And resource is SIU-locked (S+IU).

For me it sounds like (and it doesn't make any sense):

> SELECT has SIU lock, because some other session has an intent to do an UPDATE

Can anybody, please, explain me why `SELECT` holds a `SIU` lock?

**UPDATE:** The select statement is autogenerated by EF 6.1.2; update statement is a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Is this a multi-statement transaction? Note, that your update cannot use any indexes. Might not be what you intended.

Comment: Zooming in shows it has a nested subquery.

Comment: What's the transaction isolation level? You can find it in the deadlock graph's xml.

Comment: Similar issue potentially here?  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89460/deadlock-due-to-concurrent-updates-with-siu-lock

Comment: @usr, those are not multi-statement transactions

Comment: @underscore_d, I agree it has subquery and all of them are SELECT. So, does it explain, why even with nesting my SELECT holds SIU (share with intent update) lock?

Comment: @BenThul, I don't explicitly set isolation level, so it is the default one - Read Commited

Comment: @Sumo, it is similar, but not exactly. The difference is that there guy has 2 updates and that expains the SIU lock, but in my case I have only one UPDATE and the other is SELECT, which holds SIU lock (lock designed for updates)

Comment: @davidoff: trust but verify. That query looks like it was generated by an orm and at least one of the orms that I've dealt with helpfully sets it to serializable.

Comment: @BenThul, you're right about ORM. It's Entity Framework 6. After a quick research I didn't find an easy way to get a transaction isolation level from profiler data, but I did find an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/04/01/tips-to-avoid-deadlocks-in-entity-framework-applications.aspx), which says: _Entity Framework never implicitly introduces transactions on queries_. So I assume in the worst case I'll have default Isolation level of my DB, which is set to READ COMMITED.

Comment: As I said above, you can find it in the deadlock XML (or, more precisely, you can find the isolation level for each process involved in the deadlock). And the worst case isn't read committed - at least one ORM has a default of serializable (which to me would explain the SIU lock).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will turn out that there was DML executing under the same transaction. I know you stated this was not the case but I really don't see how selects can take write locks.

**Attach profiler and capture all statements and transaction operations** (the `TM` events). Maybe you'll find more going on in the same session and transaction than you expect.

Submitting this guess as an answers because it seems quite likely to be the solution.

Comment: Would be nice if the "log used" was non zero then we could know for sure that must be the case.